# Negation of set membership, equality

Tags: isabelle

I noticed that Isabelle automatically simplifies `¬ (a ∈ (- A))` and `¬ (x = y)` to `a ∉ A` and `x ≠ y`, respectively.

Here is a simple pen-and-paper proof in natural deduction but fails in Isabelle. In the 2nd line, `¬ (a ∈ (- A))` is simplified to `a ∉ - A`. From the latter, we cannot apply ComplD, but why?

```
lemma "- (- A) ⊆ (A::'a set)"   
proof 
   fix a assume "a ∈ - (- A)"
   hence "¬ (a ∈ (- A))" by (rule ComplD)
   hence "¬ (¬ (a ∈ A))" by (rule ComplD) (* fail! *)
   thus "a ∈ A" by (rule notnotD)
qed
```

Is there a way to go back to the non-simplified expression?

Of course, the lemma can be proved in one line by simp. But my purpose is to explicitly use natural deduction rules (for teaching).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not simplifications. If you look at the definitions of `a ≠ b` and `x ∉ A` in Isabelle (e.g. by ctrl-clicking on the symbols), you will find that they are simply abbreviations for `¬(a = b)` and `¬(x ∈ A)`. The statements are internally represented exactly the way you wrote them above, they are just printed differently for increased readability.

The reason why you cannot apply the rule `ComplD` is that it simply does not match. `ComplD` says that `?c ∈ - ?A ⟹ ?c ∉ ?A`. However, in the failing step, your assumption is `a ∉ -A`, and that cannot be unified to the premise `?c ∈ -?A` of `ComplD`, and therefore `rule` fails.

I am relatively certain that you will need classical reasoning for this proof since your statement does not hold intuitionistically. This means you will have to do a proof by contradiction, e.g. like this:

```
lemma "- (- A) ⊆ (A::'a set)"   
proof
  fix a assume a: "a ∈ - (- A)"
  show "a ∈ A"
  proof (rule ccontr)
    assume "a ∉ A"
    have "a ∈ -A"
    proof (rule ComplI)
      assume "a ∈ A"
      with ‹a ∉ A› show False by contradiction
    qed
    moreover from a have "a ∉ -A" by (rule ComplD)
    ultimately show False by contradiction
  qed
qed
```

The `rule ccontr` in there starts the proof by contradiction; the proof method `contradiction` is merely a nice way to derive anything when one has proven a fact and its negation.

Comment: Yes, of course rule ComplI doesn't work ! I can't believe that I didn't realize that! Thanks a lot!